# Python psycopg2 create dynamic ID and import json file

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

I got and error **"null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint"** after import json file to psycopg2. It's possible to create dynamic ID then import json file in psycopg? because my json file have no ID and not allow to put ID's in json.

I created table like this:

```
create table item_free(
        "id" serial NOT NULL,
        "item_1" varchar(2000),
        "item_2" varchar(2000),
        "item_3" varchar(2000),
        "item_4" varchar(2000),
        "item_5" varchar(2000),
        "item_6" varchar(2000),
        "item_7" varchar(2000),
        "item_8" varchar(2000),
        "item_9" varchar(2000),
        "item_10" varchar(2000),
        PRIMARY KEY ( "id" )
);

SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('item_free', 'id'), COALESCE(max(id)+1, 1), FALSE) FROM item_free;
```

And my json file look like:

```
{
    "item_1": "Test",
    "item_2": null,
    "item_3": "Sample",
    "item_4": null,
    "item_5": "Milk,
    "item_6": null,
    "item_7": "Drinks",
    "item_8": null,
    "item_9": null,
    "item_10": null
},
```

This is my code to import json file:

```
with psycopg2.connect(host='0.0.0.0', port='0000' ,dbname='Test', user='TEST', password='TEST') as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        with open('../json/file/Location/file.json') as my_file:
            data = json.load(my_file)
           ********Some code here ***
        query_sql = """ insert into item_free
            select * from json_populate_recordset(NULL::item_free, %s) """
        cur.execute(query_sql, (json.dumps(data),))
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
    query_sql = """ insert into item_free
        select * from json_populate_recordset(NULL::item_free, %s) """
```

Phrase it more explicitly:

```
    query_sql = """ insert into item_free (
            item_1,
            item_2,
            ...
            item_10)
        select * from json_populate_recordset(NULL::item_free, %s) """
```

`id` is not mentioned,
so it will offer the usual `serial` defaulting behavior,
generating a distinct integer.